# configure monit on linux to monitor a process and then reboot

Tags: linux, centos, monit

I would like monit to monitor my service and once it's stopped then I want the computer 
to reboot. The process don't have a certain port that I can monitor. This is what I did:

```
check process chat with pidfile /var/run/chat.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
if changed ppid then exec /sbin/reboot
```

I tried all sort of things but it only restart my service.

Any suggestion.

Comment: Why reboot? There aren't many good reasons to reboot a linux server, most of the time you can simply restart services to achieve the same effect. Linux is designed to run for long periods of time without reboot.

Comment: did you fix the `ppid` to `pid` because checking the parent pid for a service is always going to be wrong. If so you should update your question.

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem on my CentOS 6.2 instances, in that I cannot get it to exec simple commands, hence I have submitted a question to the monit users mailing list, but as yet got no response. http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2012-03/msg00053.html

Answer (score 1):

I think ppid might refer to the parent id, which will always be 1 for a service, so use

```
check process chat with pidfile /var/run/chat.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
if changed pid then exec /sbin/reboot
```

instead.   i tested this with some local service, and it works for me, restarting the service causes the server to reboot. (whether this is a good idea generally is another matter... ;-)

from the man page....

> PID TESTING
>
> Monit can test the process identification number (pid) of a process
>   for changes. This test is implicit and Monit will send a alert in the
>   case of failure by default.
>
> The syntax for the pid statement is: IF CHANGED PID [[]  CYCLES
>   ] THEN action action is a choice of " ALERT ", " RESTART ", " START ",
>   " STOP ", " EXEC ", " MONITOR " or " UNMONITOR ".
>
> This test is useful to detect possible process restarts which has
>   occurred in the timeframe between two Monit testing cycles. In the
>   case that the restart was fast and the process provides expected
>   service (i.e. all tests succeeded) you will be notified that the
>   process was replaced.
>
> For example sshd daemon can restart very quickly, thus if someone
>   changes its configuration and do sshd restart outside of Monit's
>   control you will be notified that the process was replaced by a new
>   instance (or you can optionally do some other action such as
>   preventively stop sshd).
>
> Another example is a MySQL Cluster which has its own watchdog with
>   process restart ability. You can use Monit for redundant monitoring.
>
> Example:
>
> check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
>         if changed pid then exec "/my/script"
>
> PPID TESTING
>
> Monit can test the process parent process identification number (ppid)
>   of a process for changes. This test is implicit and Monit will send
>   alert in the case of failure by default.
>
> The syntax for the ppid statement is: IF CHANGED PPID [[] 
>   CYCLES ] THEN action action is a choice of " ALERT ", " RESTART ", "
>   START ", " STOP ", " EXEC ", " MONITOR " or " UNMONITOR ".
>
> This test is useful for detecting changes of a process parent.
>
> Example:
>
> check process myproc with pidfile /var/run/myproc.pid
>         if changed ppid then exec "/my/script"

Comment: That's what I did but it won't reboot. it will only restart the service. I need the server to reboot once the process is dead

Comment: I also tried :check process chat with pidfile /var/run/chat.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/chat start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop"
if 1 restarts within 1 cycles then exec /sbin/reboot

Comment: the `stop program = "/etc/init.d/chat stop` and start directives allow monit to control the service, like `monit chat start`. I tested the example above and it definitely works for me. If you restart chat, and it gets another pid, then the server reboots.

Comment: Basically if the above stanzas are not working for you, and `service chat restart` and `monit chat restart` do not cause the server to reboot, then its probably that the chat init script is not working properly. If you provide the output of the following commands in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) you might see the issue. `ps -ef | grep chat; monit chat restart; ps -ef | grep chat`

Comment: there is a typo in that last comment try this instead ``ps -ef | grep chat; service chat restart; ps -ef | grep chat``

Comment: interestingly this works on my local fedora box which is running monit-5.2.5-3.fc16.x86_64 but not on my centos server with monit-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to monitor arbitrary processes from the outside; conversely, it is trivial to control processes started by you.

I would suggest you investigate [**runit**](http://smarden.org/runit/), an alternative init daemon for servers.

Comment: Monit doesn't monitor from the outside.

Comment: @kyle depends on your definition since you can monitor services on another host that Monit's not running on...I'd say that's "outside" the Monit process.

Comment: You could I suppose, but not if you're checking the pid as in the question.